# Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder exception

Tags: java, maven, swagger, swagger-codegen

**Machine configuration**

I am using

- Windows 11
- jdk-11.0.4
- v3.0.43_codegen
- apache-maven-3.8.8-bin

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to generate SDK project for my ASP.Net Core application using OpenAPI3.0.
I am following the steps mentioned in this GitHub repo https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/#readme

But ended up with the below exception.

```
PS D:\OpenAPI\v3.0.43_codegen\swagger-codegen-3.0.43\swagger-codegen-3.0.43> java -jar modules\swagger-codegen-cli\target\swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i D:\petstore.json -l php -o c:\temp\petstore_local_api_client
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation.
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

**I tried the below.**

1. I have the slf4j-simple-2.0.7.jar and slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar in classpath of environment variable.
2. I have the slf4j-simple-2.0.7.jar and slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar in D:\OpenAPI\v3.0.43_codegen\swagger-codegen-3.0.43\swagger-codegen-3.0.43 which is the root folder in powershell
3. I have the slf4j-simple-2.0.7.jar and slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar in :\OpenAPI\v3.0.43_codegen\swagger-codegen-3.0.43\swagger-codegen-3.0.43\ modules\swagger-codegen-cli\target\ where the swagger-codegen-cli.jar is available.

**Note**

There is no exception when I try with master source or2.x.x source of CodeGen. This issue is raised when I am trying to use CodeGen 3.X.X version of source. Since I am trying to adapt OpenAPI spec 3.0 can someone help me with this?

Comment: If using another codegen is an option, try [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) instead.

Comment: The StaticLoggerBinder error looks like a [known issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/12135). Did you build swagger-codegen-cli from source code yourself? If so, try instead using the prebuilt JAR from Maven Central and see if it works: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/codegen/v3/swagger-codegen-cli/3.0.43/swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.43.jar

Comment: Thanks. Now I am trying to use https://openapi-generator.tech/